# Makefile and sub makefile, phony task nothing to be done

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Directory tree

```
.
| Makefile
| src
    | Makefile
| spec
| test
```

in ./Makefile

```
default: all

.DEFAULT: 
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

in src/Makefile

```
.PHONY: all spec test ...

spec:
    bundle exec cucumber ../spec
```

When I am in the src directory the "make spec" works well.

```
..././src/# make spec
blablabla
```

But when I am in the root directory i get that there is "nothing to be done" but it is a phony target

```
..././# make spec
make: Nothing to be done for `spec'.
```

I suppose it is a problem with the name of task that is the same as the name of the directory, with a sub makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suppose it is a problem with the name of task that is the same as the name of the directory, with a sub makefile.

Yep.

Try something like:

```
all :

forward_ : ;

% : forward_
    $(MAKE) -C $@

.PHONY : all forward_
```

Phony `forward_` target is supposed to trigger re-evaluation of `%` target even when there is an existing file or directory with `$@` name.